# Error "InvalidFirebaseData" while sending Data to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type DemoApp.SendMessageInput at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.`

This is how I'm  trying to send.
Above error does not occur if I use normal dictionary to pass data but I want to do it via Model as one or more time I can simply call that model for input rather than dic os if changes happens in future then I have make changes in one file only.

```
    let messageItem = SendMessageInput(content: text, displayName: currrentUser.name, fileLength: 0, fileUrl: "", fromID: currrentUser.userId, isRead: false, messageStatus: 0, messageType: MessageType.text.rawValue, timestamp: Timestamp, toID: self.toUserID)

    itemRef.setValue(messageItem)
```

SendMessageInput.swift

```
class SendMessageInput: Reflect{
    var content: String = ""
    var displayName: String = ""
    var fileLength: Int = 0
    var fileUrl: String = ""
    var fromID: String = ""
    var isRead: Bool = false
    var messageStatus: Int = 0
    var messageType: String = ""
    var timestamp: Int = 0
    var toID: String = ""

    var values:[String: AnyObject]{
        let arrayValue: [Any] = [content, displayName, fileLength, fileUrl, fromID, isRead, messageStatus, messageType, timestamp, toID]
        var dic: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
        for index in 0..<self.getProperties().count{
            dic[self.getProperties()[index]] = arrayValue[index] as AnyObject?
        }
        return dic
    }

    init(content: String, displayName: String, fileLength: Int, fileUrl: String, fromID: String, isRead: Bool, messageStatus: Int, messageType: String, timestamp: Int, toID: String) {
        self.displayName = displayName
        self.fileLength = fileLength
        self.fileUrl = fileUrl
        self.fromID = fromID
        self.isRead = isRead
        self.messageStatus = messageStatus
        self.messageType = messageType
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.toID = toID
    }

}
```

Reflect.swift

```
class Reflect: NSObject {

    func getProperties()->[String] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        var properties = [String]()
        for childern in mirror.children {
            if childern.label == "super"{continue}
            properties.append(childern.label!)
        }
        return properties
    }

    func getClassName() -> String {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return String(describing: mirror.subjectType)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `.setValue()` on arbitrary objects.

It looks like you're forgetting to call `.values` on your object. Try this

```
itemRef.setValue(messageItem.values)
```

Comment: Thanks I completely forgot that.